# jQuery,Fancybox show php page with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, lightbox

I am having a problem that is driving me crazy!.

I am using Fancybox.net as lightbox on my site.

I need to show a php page in the fancybox that is called by a click function.

I have no idea how to do it, so I have tried the solution below.

But I always get the error that the page can not be loaded.

I know the code is totally wrong, I hope you can help me.

I just need to show a php page inside the fancybox when the click function is called.

```
$('#StatusMessage').click(function() {


$.fancybox(
    {
            'autoDimensions'    : false,
        'width'                 : 350,
        'height'                : 'auto',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'ajax'   : {
    cache   : false,
    url     : "modules/mymodule/index.php"
}
    }
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in an edit. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> OK I SOLVED THE ISSUE. THANKS ANYWAY:

```
$('#StatusMessage').click(function() {
 $.fancybox(
    {
            'autoDimensions'    : false,
        'width'                 : 350,
        'height'                : 'auto',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'href'          : 'modules/mymodule/index.php'
    }
);
});
```